# On the Stone Von Neumann theorem: Why is this a (non orthogonal basis of $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

In the proof of the Stone Von Neumann theorem of the Folland's book "Harmonic Analysis in phase space", he says that the functions:
$$ \phi^{ab}(x)=e^{2\pi i bx+\pi i ab}e^{-\pi(x+a)^2} $$
are a (non orthogonal) basis of $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

Why is it a basis?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener's_tauberian_theorem  
Translated gaussians (ingoring the complex exponential factor in front) are dense in $L^2$ and hence for a basis.

Comment: Besides orthonormal bases, I know of Schauder bases, and Hamel bases.  What kind of basis do you have in mind?  Or are you just thinking of a set spanning a dense subspace?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that powerful theorem. The exponential factor can be ignored? Reading the book I think I find out another proof based purely on the analysis of Heisenberg group (I will posted it shortly).

Comment: @Ruy, yes, my question was if they span a dense subspace

Comment: Set $b=0$ (you dont need the additional modulation) for your set to be a basis. You can still "enlarge" your overcomplete basis by considering $b \neq 0$ if you really want to.

Comment: I see that we don't need this fact to proof the theorem. Without using this, Follands proof state that the we can find an isometric equivalence between irreducible representation, and by Schur lemma is an unitary equivalence.